Small algorithm to create a list of y-axes in python
On python, I have a function called get_list_axes which takes 2 parameters :

A list of unique captors - let's call them ["A", "B", "C", D"].
A list of captors from the unique captors above which should share the same y-axis - For instance ["A", "D"] or ["A", "C"] or ["A", "B", "D"], etc.



The goal of the function is to return a list of y-axis depending on the list of captors to merge on the same y-axis. When there is nothing to merge, it should then return ["y1", "y2", "y3", "y4"].

The function is as follows :
def get_list_axes(list_ana_captors: list, merge_captors: list) -> list:
    counter_no_merge, counter_merge = 1, 1
    list_axes = ["y1"]

    for captor in list_ana_captors[1:]:
        if captor not in merge_captors or captor == merge_captors[0]:
            if captor == merge_captors[0]:
                counter_merge = counter_no_merge + 1
            counter_no_merge = counter_no_merge + 1

        if captor not in merge_captors:
            list_axes.append(f"y{counter_no_merge}")
        else:
            list_axes.append(f"y{counter_merge}")
    return list_axes


Now, let's define our list of unique captors list_captors = ["A", "B", "C", "D"].
Basically, my problem is that whenever the list of captors to merge is in the same order than the list of captors list_captors, everything works, for instance :

get_list_axes(list_captors, ["A", "B", "C", "D"]) = ['y1', 'y1', 'y1', 'y1']
get_list_axes(list_captors, ["B", "C", "D"]) = ['y1', 'y2', 'y2', 'y2']
get_list_axes(list_captors, ["A", "B"]) = ['y1', 'y1', 'y2', 'y3']
get_list_axes(list_captors, ["A", "C"]) = ['y1', 'y2', 'y1', 'y3']
get_list_axes(list_captors, ["A", "D"]) = ['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y1']
get_list_axes(list_captors, ["B", "D"]) = ['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y2']

However, if we try in reverse :

get_list_axes(list_captors, ["D", "A"]) = ['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4'] instead of ['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y1']
get_list_axes(list_captors, ["D", "C"]) = ['y1', 'y2', 'y1', 'y3'] instead of ['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y3']
get_list_axes(list_captors, ["D", "B"]) = ['y1', 'y1', 'y2', 'y3'] instead of ['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y2']
get_list_axes(list_captors, ["D", "C", "A", "B"]) = ['y1', 'y1', 'y1', 'y2'] instead of ['y1', 'y1', 'y1', 'y1']

Is there an easier way than what I am currently doing ?

Session Info :
-----
session_info        1.0.0
-----
IPython             8.12.3
jupyter_client      8.6.2
jupyter_core        5.7.2
-----
Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:57:54) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)]
Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
-----
Session information updated at 2024-07-30 15:15


Your original get_list_axes function fails when merge_captors is not in the same order as list_ana_captors. This is because it relies on the specific order of captors, causing incorrect y-axis assignments.
To fix this, we map each captor to its y-axis, ensuring captors in merge_captors share the same y-axis regardless of their order.
Code:
def get_list_axes(list_ana_captors: list, merge_captors: list) -> list:
    list_axes = []
    captor_to_axis = {}
    current_y = 1

    for captor in list_ana_captors:
        if captor in merge_captors:
            if merge_captors[0] not in captor_to_axis:
                captor_to_axis[merge_captors[0]] = f"y{current_y}"
                current_y += 1
            captor_to_axis[captor] = captor_to_axis[merge_captors[0]]
        else:
            captor_to_axis[captor] = f"y{current_y}"
            current_y += 1

    for captor in list_ana_captors:
        list_axes.append(captor_to_axis[captor])

    return list_axes

Hope it will help, if you have any question feel free to ask.

Exactly what I was looking for and missing on my previous function ! @nk0
